# Setting Api version in Azure automation account using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I was using the following consumption usage detail in powershell azure automation runbook.

```
Get-AzureRmConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate -ResourceGroup
```

The same command and runbook works fine in another subscription.
But in one of the subscription it gives the following error

> Subscription scope usage is not supported for current api version.
> Please use api version after  2019-10-01

How to set apiversion in Azure Powershell ?

Comment: Try to use `Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail` instead of `Get-AzureRmConsumptionUsageDetail`. Az is a new module.

Comment: Same issue with Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail

Answer (score 2):

`Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail` do not have `ApiVersion` parameter.

My workaround is to use the command below. First, get the token with your login account, and then request the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list) to get the usage details. The `api-version` is 2019-10-01 what the error mentioned.

```
# login
Connect-AzAccount

# get accessToken
$resource = "https://management.azure.com"
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$accessToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, $resource).AccessToken

#request REST API
$uri = "https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2019-10-01"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri $uri -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer " + $accessToken }
```

`{scope}` should be instead of the scope associated with usage details operations. You could refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list#uri-parameters) for more details.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work